# How to get all the changes for a particular project, branch with start date and end date

Tags: python, rest, gerrit

I want to get all the changes from Gerrit using Gerrit rest API given

1. REPO name
2. branch name
3. start date - the date from which I want the review.
4. end date - the date till which I want the reviews from the start date.

so far I have tried this:

```
rest = GerritRestAPI(url=gerrit_url)
changes = rest.get('projects/{project name}')
```

but this is giving me the project information but I want the changes.

I want something like this

```
changes = rest.get('projects/{project name}/branch/{branchname}/startdate/{startdate}/enddate/{enddate}')
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
changes = rest.get('changes/?q=project:{projectname}+branch:{branchnme}+after:{startdate}+before:{enddate}')
```

Comment: if I want to get the comments for each review, how can I get using this command
i don't want to run different command rest.get('changes/change-id/comments').

Comment: You get the list of the published comments of all revisions of a change using rest.get('changes/{change-id}/comments').